# Convert all images ( png; jpg ) of hugo website to webp

Tags: image, hugo

How to convert all images of my hugo project in webp

knowing that i use this code to show featured images of posts:

```
 <figure class="image-f">
        {{ with .Params.images }}
        <a href="{{ $permalink }}"><img loading="lazy" src="{{ index . 0 }}" alt=""></a>
        {{ end }}
    </figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure class="image-f">
  {{ with .Params.images }}
    {{ if (resources.GetMatch (index . 0)) }}
      <a href="{{ $permalink }}">
        <img 
          loading="lazy" 
          src="{{ ((resources.GetMatch (index . 0)).Resize "600x webp").RelPermalink }}" 
          alt="">
      </a>
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
</figure>
```

What this does:

1. Check if .Params.images exist with the 'with' statement
2. Check if the first item in .Params.images is a valid resource with 'index 0' and 'GetMatch'.
3. Resize the first image to 600 pixels wide and convert it to webp with the '.Resize' statement with value '600x webp'.
4. Get the permalink of the resized image with the '.RelPermalink' command.

Note that this code ignores the other images in the .Params.images array, just like the original code did.

Source: [Resize all images - HugoCodex](https://hugocodex.org/blog/resize-all-images/)